# What is the URL for the login form?

Tags: authentication-authorization

I am trying to log in on a Drupal site, but the site doesn't have the login block enabled.

How can I find the URL for the login form?

Answer (score 4):

Drupal default login URL format,

**example.com/user**

Answer (score 2):

You can also check http://example.com/?q=user/login if the clean url is not enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing is working, then there is a possibility that the user has overridden the `user.tpl.php` for that you can use

## http://example.com/user/login

same way for directly resetting the password you can access `user/password` and for getting logged out directly from a Drupal site if you're unable to find any option then you can use `user/logout`

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

With Drupal, if the login block isn't shown in any page, you can see the login form visiting the user/login path. If you are already logged in, Drupal will return a 403 error, since only users who still have to log in can access that page.
If you visit http://example.com/user (replace example.com with the domain of your site), you will see your user profile page, if you are logged in, or you will be redirected to the login form, if you aren't logged in.

If clean URLs aren't enabled, the login form will be visible on http://example.com/?q=user/login, while the user profile page will be visible on http://example.com/?q=user. (Replace example.com with the domain of the Drupal site.)